# Is it possible to replace Windows with Ubuntu on the Intel Compute Stick that has Windows pre-installed?

Tags: system-installation, hardware, intel

Intel are releasing two versions of the [Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html). There's a Windows one and an Ubuntu one, with the Windows one having a higher price but also better hardware specs.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu onto the Windows version of the Compute Stick by following the usual installation procedure?

Comment: I doubt it will be possible at all.

Comment: Any chance this question can be re-opened? I've edited it to make it less opinion-based. Happy to incorporate any further edits if it will help get to the question being open & a good answer.

Comment: they say it is possible, but from the looks of it the dirvers are not provided in a public space(no wifi), thus you need to manually contact manufactures to obtain or use a unofficial image for ubuntu - not worth the hassle - also voids the warranty from what I read.